# Leaflet info box only showing properties from selected layer

Tags: leaflet

I would like to use the info box as shown in the tutorial [interactive choropleth map](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) with multiple layers and properties from different layers.
The idea is to only show the properties from the selected layer.

For example the infobox has both Statename and Cityname as properties. Statename is a property in the layer States and Cityname is a property in the layer Cities.

```
var info = L.control({position:'topleft'});

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;};

info.update = function (pro) {
this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Information</h4>' +  (pro ?
    '<b>State ' + pro.Statename + '</b><br />City ' + pro.Cityname + ''
    : 'hover over map');};

info.addTo(map);
```

And to use the infobox the following three parts within the var for each layer

```
function infoFeatureStates(e) {
var layer = e.target;
info.update(layer.feature.properties);}
```

To empty the infobox

```
function resetInfoState(e) {
info.update();}
```

Eventlistener

```
function onEachFeatureState(feature, layer) {
layer.on({
    mouseover: infoFeatureState,
    mouseout: resetInfoState,});}
```

And similar functions for the other layer: infoFeatureCities, resetInfoCities, onEachFeatureCity.

When hovering over a feature from the layer States, the infobox now shows both properties, with the correct value for Statename and showing Cityname 'Undefined' as it is not a property of that layer. And vice versa when hovering over a feature from Cities layer.

I would like the info box to only be populated by the properties that are part of the selected layer (based on the feature selected by mouseover). So it doesn't show Cityname Undefined when hovering over a feature from layer States.

How do I tell the infobox with property belongs to which layer?
And how do I change which properties are shown depending on which feature (layer) is selected?

Or should I build something else completely?

Comment: Seeing some of your code would be helpful in helping you.

Comment: I suggest you to review these posts: 1. [Leaflet: 4 overlay layers, 1 click, get properties of all intersecting polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/245090/29431) 2. [Get all features of all layers clicked in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38599872/5569709)

Comment: This may help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315564/turf-intersect-point-with-leaflet-geojson-error/315570?noredirect=1#comment514400_315570, Here http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/pointsinpoly/index.html   I put results in a bootstrap dialog, but you could push them to a sidebar table or div just as easily. Just need something to like map.hasLayer() to determine if visible.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to show only info of topmost feature when features overlap?

Comment: Yes, only info of topmost feature when features overlap AND only show given attribute name (State or City) if this attribute is part of topmost layer. Now the infobox might show "State Oregon" and "City Undefined" and I would like it to only show "State Oregon" when Cityname is not a property of the feature selected / topmost feautue.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to display info about topmost feature, simply ignore `undefined` properties:

```
info.update = function (pro) {
  var lineBreak = '';
  this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Information</h4>';

  if (pro.Statename !== undefined) {
    this._div.innerHTML += '<b>State ' + pro.Statename + '</b>';
    lineBreak = '<br />'
  }
  if (pro.Cityname !== undefined) {
    this._div.innerHTML += lineBreak + '<b>State ' + pro.Statename + '</b>';
  }
};
```

Comment: I like your idea, however I can not get it to work at this moment. The map does not render, so I am making some mistake somewhere. To me it doesn't seem correct to have pro.Statename in both if blocks. Where does the 'hover over map part go to?