# Leaflet dialog box that contains info on 1 to n layers that were clicked on

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have a Leaflet application where the user can click on a feature and the info for that feature will be updated in dialog box.

```
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Property Info</h4>' +  (props ? '<b>Address: '+ props.address +'<br>Property Type: '+props.buff+'<br>Buffer Distance: '+props.buff_dist: 'Click on a Property Pal');
};
info.addTo(map);

var theMarker={}
var main_layer;
map.on('click', function(e) {
    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.GeoJSON) {
            layer.eachLayer(function(l){layer.resetStyle(l);});
        };
    });
    var str = "Latitude: " + e.latlng.lat.toFixed(5) + " Longitude: " + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(5) + " Zoom Level: " + map.getZoom();
    var lat = e.latlng.lat;
    var lng = e.latlng.lng;
    ProcessClick(lat,lng,str)
});

function ProcessClick(lat,lng,str){
    if (theMarker != undefined) {
      map.removeLayer(theMarker);
    };
    theMarker=L.marker([lat,lng],{icon: pineapple_icon}).addTo(map);
    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.GeoJSON) {
            layer.eachLayer(function(layer2) {
                var click_intersection = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(theMarker.toGeoJSON(), layer2.toGeoJSON());
                if (click_intersection) {
                    layer2.setStyle({fillColor: 'lightblue', opacity: 0.8});
                    var i=layer2.feature.properties;
                    console.log(layer2.feature.properties);
                    info.update(i);
                };
            });
        }
    });
    $("#map_coords").html(str);
};
```

The code is setup so the user can click on multiple overlapping features but only the last feature that is clicked gets its info displayed in the dialog box on the top right.

Picture below explanation: the childcare and religious buffers layers are displayed on the map. in this example I click on an overlapping childcare and religious buffer. When I click on these features they get highlighted and the info from these two features updates the top right dialog box (would this be called a dialog box?).

What I want: A dialog box that stores all the info from the features that are clicked. A way to scroll through the results and when info from one feature is displayed in the dialog box, only that feature will be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Leaflet-pip plugin (https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) might come handy here (see QA https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245090/leaflet-4-overlay-layers-1-click-get-properties-of-all-intersecting-polygons)

Comment: The issue isn't getting the info from multiple layers. My code does that. The issue is displaying all of it at once in some sort of scrollable dialog box

Comment: Maybe this question is more meant for stackoverflow...

Comment: I didn't scroll down your code so I didn't notice you are using turf to detect all layers. As far as your question qoes, it's then really of pure HTML nature.

Comment: Here is a link to a similar question, In my answer I pushed the results to a bootstrap dialog with tabs for each layer. The data was pushed to variables but could have been arrays for more info. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315564/turf-intersect-point-with-leaflet-geojson-error/315570?noredirect=1#comment514400_315570
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/pointsinpoly/indextab.html

Comment: how do I migrate this to Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to do this:

changes I made to the process

1. in the ProcessClick function I pass through a JS object in third parameter,which 
   stores the intersected layers info and GEOMETRY
2. Now on each click the selected geometries do not reset (I have a separate div for resetting them)
3. in the Info div I added an onlick function -- everytime the user clicks on this div
   the info from the first item in the JS object (the layer selection that got passed
   thourhg the ProcessClick function) updates the info div and the geometry of that 
   record/item gets rendered as the selected geom (seen in pink). on each click the counter
   n gets a +1
4. when the counter exceeds the length of the layer_selection JS object the n count resets to 0, layer_selection is cleared
   and the all the layers that were clicked on return to there normal colors.

   ```
       var selected_geom={};
   info.onAdd = function (map) {
       this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); 
       this._div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
       this._div.type="button";
       var n=0;
       this._div.onclick=function(){
           if (selected_geom != undefined) {
               map.removeLayer(selected_geom);
           };
           info.update(layer_selection[Object.keys(layer_selection)[n]]);
           var geom=layer_selection[Object.keys(layer_selection)[n]]['geometry'];
           selected_geom=L.geoJSON(geom,{
               style: {"color": "#ff00bf",
                       "weight": 10,
                       "opacity": 1
                       }
               }).addTo(map);
           n=(n+1);
           if (n>=Object.keys(layer_selection).length){
               layer_selection={};
               n=0;
               map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
                   if (layer instanceof L.GeoJSON) {
                       layer.eachLayer(function(l){layer.resetStyle(l)})
                   }
               });
           }
         };
       this.update();
       return this._div;
   };

   info.update = function (props) {
       this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Property Info</h4>' +  (props ? '<b>Address: '+ props.address +'<br>Property Type: '+props.buff+'<br>Buffer Distance: '+props.buff_dist: 'Click on a Property Pal');
   };
   info.addTo(map);

   var theMarker={};
   layer_selection={};
   map.on('click', function(e) {
       var lat = e.latlng.lat;
       var lng = e.latlng.lng;
       ProcessClick(lat,lng,layer_selection);
   });


   function ProcessClick(lat,lng,ls={}){
       if (theMarker != undefined) {
           map.removeLayer(theMarker);
       };
       theMarker=L.marker([lat,lng],{icon: pineapple_icon}).addTo(map);
       var i = 0;
       map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
           if (layer instanceof L.GeoJSON) {
               layer.eachLayer(function(layer2) {
                   var click_intersection = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(theMarker.toGeoJSON(), layer2.toGeoJSON());
                   if (click_intersection) {
                       layer2.setStyle({fillColor: '#ffff00', opacity: 0.8});
                       i++;
                       props=layer2.feature.properties;
                       props['geometry']=layer2.toGeoJSON();
                       ls[i]=props;
                   };
               });
           }
       });
   };
   ```

pics:

two overlapping polygons, green and orange

[image]

when they are both clicked on both of the selected features turn yellow
[image]

when the property info div is clicked on the first item of the selectiions info updates the div and the corresponding geometry shows up in a pink outline. and the next click does the same for the next selected features...

[image]